# Python suds showing the following issues "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, suds

I'm in the process of invoking a documentum webservice for which I am starting with a simple code:

```
from suds.client import Client #@UnresolvedImport  
from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated  
import urllib2  
t=HttpAuthenticated(username='x', password='x')  
t.handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(t.pm)  
t.urlopener = urllib2.build_opener(t.handler)  
url = 'http://hudt17:8888/services/core/ObjectService?wsdl'  
client = Client(url,transport=t)  
print client
```

It works fine if `url='http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl'`. But I have this error thrown back to me if it's not:

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1Qk8_qji385B9fZB-z4eMbPc1fv1AXVKEtbxr7Xx6AvQ

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

There is a patch for this issue:

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/attachment/ticket/239/recurselevel-schema.py.patch

Click on the Original Format link at the bottom of the page.   You can then apply the patch using:

`patch schema.py < recurselevel-schema.py.patch`

Then install from the suds source top level dir using:

`easy_install .`

Comment: this patch don't work for current suds version? I get suds-0.4-py2.7 and I get Hunk #2 FAILED at 397

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an XSD schema which refers to itself.

Or which refers to another schema which refers to the first one.

In any case one or more schemas which have a circular dependence.

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a blocking bug on the Suds issue tracker: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/239

Unfortunately, this issue has been open for more than 3 years, as of 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue consuming a huge wsdl with multiple includes and circular calls.  The 0.6 version of suds-jurko does not support this, but the current developers cut v0.7 seems to solve this issue.

1. Download latest zip and extract:  (Find the tip tag, or latest tag or branch)
   https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/downloads
2. Install:

   ```
   $ sudo easy_install .
   ```
3. Verify:

   ```
   $ pip freeze
   ```

Should show:

> suds-jurko==0.7.dev0

Comment: It looks like suds-jurko version 0.7.dev0 doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: Try this: sudo pip install https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/get/tip.tar.gz#egg=suds   -- Only add https:// in front of bitbucket, Stack overflow wont let me comment with the http in the link